# MongoDB Json document structure

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I'm creating a web app using MEAN. I am looking at the AngularJS tutorials and they have a large JSON file with all products inside, then separate JSON files for each product.

link: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08

If I'm using MongoDB and have this data.

```
"title: Grand Theft Auto V",
"genre": "Genre: Action, Adventure",
"developer": "Developer: Rockstar North",
"releasedate": "Release Date: 2015. April 14. (PC)",
"publisher": "Publisher: Rockstar Games ",
"rcpu": "Intel Core i5 3470 @ 3.2GHZ (4 CPUs) / AMD X8 FX-8350 @ 4GHZ",
"rram": "8GB",
"rgpu": "NVIDIA GTX 660 2GB / AMD HD7870 2GB",
"directx": "12",
"operatingsystem": "Windows 7 ",
"storage": "65GB",
"mcpu": "Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q6600/AMD Phenom 9850 Quad-Core Processor",
"mgpu": "NVIDIA 9800 GT 1GB / AMD HD 4870 1GB",
"ram": "4GB"
```

I want to have a list of all the games with titles, then once clicked loads the system requirements.

What would be the best way to house the data?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I think your question is not clear. When you ask 'What would the best way to house the data?' Do you mean: 1) What would be the best database technology for your task; 2) What would be the best database schema/model or 3) What would be the best way to harvest the data and feed your database. Or none of them. Please, specify.

Comment: @Hector - MEAN Stands for **M**ongoDB **E**xpress.JS **A**ngular.JS **N**ode.JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, you can follow [this post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) to create a REST API for your Games.

Now you would need the data for the list of games. To get that you can do something like:

```
db.collection('games').find({}, {title: 1}, function(err, games){
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    if(games) res.json(200, games);
});
```

Now this will return you a list of game `title` and their `_id` fields.

Secondly you'll need details about a game. That you can obtain by querying the `games` collection by `_id` field. Something like this:

```
db.collection('games').findOne({_id: game_id_from_request_params}, function(err, game){
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    if(game) res.json(200, game);
});
```

This will give you details about a specific game including all the system requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so you are saying I can have the data in one document? the Angular example was https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/tree/master/app/phones See they use phones.json for little information about all of them, then a JSON file for each phone. My knowledge tells me a mongoDB document is the same as a .JSON file?

Comment: Actually a MongoDB Document is essentially a JSON Object. And a JSON Object is essentially a JavaScript Object with Key Value Pairs. Now it's up to you to decide whether to keep all the JSON Objects in one JSON File or not. What MongoDB does is maintains a Collection of Documents which are JSON Objects.

Comment: It's totally up to you how you want them to store. If this is just for practice, you can also store these JSON Objects in an Array in an AngularJS Service or Factory. And Call methods from that service or factory to get the data.

Comment: Yea, I stored the data in an array using AngularJS before, but because there are a large number of them I decided to use MongoDB. Currently I have a MongoDB document with about 50 entries similar to the example one. I just wanted to ensure that the method of storing the data was valid. Thank you

Comment: There's also a principle in MongoDB called the `Store What You're Going to Query For` Principle. Which means that you should store only that particular data in a collection that you're going to use for a particular view. So in the Angular eg that you provided, there is a phones.json that contains data that might be shown for the list view of all the phones. And then there are individual files for each phone. Each file will be consumed when a user will click on a phone and then details for that particular phone would be required. Hope you're understanding what I'm tying to explain here.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. So one query would be All phone names and makes? The next query would be specific phone data e.g. wifi and processor... So it would not be stupid to have a document for each game?